# c creating a new type without typedef

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

I'm reading some c source code and the there is a new type called 'lwm2m_object_t' defined using this syntax.

```
#define OBJ_COUNT (9)
lwm2m_object_t * objArray[OBJ_COUNT];
```

Could somebody explain how you can define a type like this? Do you not have to use `typedef`?

Is this an array of pointers of type `lwm2m_object_t`?

Thanks

Comment: _Is this an array of pointers of type lwm2m_object_t?_.... Yes, with 9 items

Comment: Surely `lwm2m_object_t` is `typedef`ed somewhere: included headers most probably

Comment: `lwm2m_object_t` is not defined here. There would be a separate `typedef` for `lwm2m_object_t` somewhere else in the code.

Comment: It is `typedef`ed in [liblwm2m.h](https://github.com/01org/liblwm2m/blob/master/core/liblwm2m.h#L210)

Comment: Many thanks for your help , a basic question I know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following:

```
lwm2m_object_t * objArray[OBJ_COUNT];
```

declares an *array of pointers to* `lwm2m_object_t`.

The type `lwm2m_object_t` is for sure somewhere else defined in the source code.

Most probably in library header [liblwm2m.h](https://github.com/01org/liblwm2m/blob/master/core/liblwm2m.h#L210).